# VLOOKUP with range where column location is not fixed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, match, vlookup

I have a situation where my data sheet have 3 columns

- ID
- FNAME
- LNAME

But sequence may change sometime such as

- FNAME
- ID
- LNAME

and

- LNAME
- FNAME
- ID

How to use `VLOOKUP` or something else to find FNAME for given ID.

Comment: Can you add some examples? You are looking up ID in what range?

Comment: You need to nest `INDEX/MATCH` for the quickest and non-volatile way of doing this.

Comment: The new `XLookup` would suit this better (if you have a version that supports it)

Comment: ^ I second that. That would indeed be even better @chrisneilsen

Comment: Another option would be to make the data into a Table, then use `Index`/`Match` or `XLookup` and use Structured References to refer to the columns by name

Answer (score 2):

To support my comment, a non-volatile way would be to nest some `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions. A simplified example:

[image]

Formula in `D7`:

```
=INDEX(A:C,MATCH("C",INDEX(A:C,,MATCH("ID",1:1,0)),0),MATCH("FNAME",1:1,0))
```

In the above we returned *"FNAME"* where *"ID"* is C dynamically. Some other positive incidental, `VLOOKUP` is equally fast as this combination of functions at **best**, but most likely slower.

Comment: Nice. I thought `VLOOKUP` cannot handle 'columns to the left'. So is it even an option? And could you elaborate a little bit on the non-volatile part. Feel free to refer to my `OFFSET` solution.

Comment: @VBasic2008, sure. `OFFSET` is a member of so called *volatile* functions. A Volatile function is one that causes recalculation of the formula in the cell where it resides every time Excel recalculates. Amongst triggers for Excel to recalculate are: Entering data, deleting, inserting, hiding, unhiding, saving, double clicking row/column divider, renaming worksheets, changing worksheet positions, open, close, etc. etc. A small number of volatile functions won't hurt as much, but the more usage the more this will impact performance. Not my dv btw.

Comment: And no, `VLOOKUP` is **not** an option =)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Don't worry, I didn't think that you would dv since my solution maybe inferior, but is still valid. But I only up vote when I get a solution to work. In my example I can use your modified solution like this: `=INDEX($A:$C,MATCH($E2,INDEX($A:$C,,MATCH($E$1,$1:$1,0)),0),MATCH(F$1,$1:$1,0))`. So my question is why didn't you lock any of the ranges?

Comment: Simply because I don't know what OP wants to do other than just a single comparison. There is no mention of multiple lookup values that implied having to drag a formula (hence I refrained from "locking", or using absolute references) @VBasic2008. Notice I mentioned: *"A simplified example"* =)

Answer (score 0):

### An INDEX/MATCH Lookup feat. OFFSET

[image]

For data in the range `A1:C6` you can use the following formula in cell `F2`:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET($A$2:$A$6,0,MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$C$1,0)-1),MATCH($E2,OFFSET($A$2:$A$6,0,MATCH($E$1,$A$1:$C$1,0)-1),0))
```

Copy down and to the right.

### How?

The initial formula is

`=INDEX(B$2:B$6,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$6,0)`

which is basically 'saying':

Find the value of cell `E2` in the range `A2:A6` and return the value in the same row from range `B2:B6`.

Now the problem is that we don't know in which column our values are. So we will use the `MATCH` function to find them starting with `FNAME`:

`=MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$C$1,0)`

but since we will be using `OFFSET` then we have to subtract `1`:

`=MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$C$1,0)-1`

Now we get our `FNAME` range where we use range `A2:A6` as the starting range:

`=OFFSET($A$2:$A$6,0,MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$C%1,0)-1)`

Think about it for a while:

If `FNAME` is found in column `A`, `MATCH` returns `1`. `OFFSET(A2:A6,,1)` returns range `B2:B6`. That is why we have to subtract `1`.

The same principle will be applied on the lookup range (`ID`):

`=OFFSET($A$2:$A$6,0,MATCH($E$1,$A$1:$C%1,0)-1)`

with the only difference that we have to lock `E1` to `$E$1` (Not `E$1`) because it will be the same for columns `F` and `G`.

Answer (score -1):

VLOOKUP works very well for a table with multiple columns of data. Here is the formula I use in Libreoffice Calc (similar to EXCEL in Linux) that references a Country lookup on B10 in a Table ($B$623:$B$684) and if found (is not #NA) proceeds to return the next column, lets say Population. A blank field is used if no match is found.

**Note** the first Table has B and B while the second lookup has B and C referencing column 2 rather than column 1. This idea can be extended for multiple columns.

```
=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(B10,$B$623:$B$684,1,0)=B10,VLOOKUP(B10,$B$623:$C$684,2,0)),"")
```